# yii2 change controller action in gridview

Tags: gridview, controller, grid, action, yii2

I have ItemController and in actionView I put gridview of my Itempicture, and I want when I click on icon view, update and delete then go to ItempictureController.

so How to change controller action in gridview with different controller?

Answer (score 22):

In your gridview,add like

```
[
  'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
  'template' => '{new_action1}{new_action2}',
  'buttons' => [
    'new_action1' => function ($url, $model) {
        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', 'controller/action?id='.$model->id, [
                    'title' => Yii::t('app', 'New Action1'),
        ]);
    }
  ],
],
```

Hope this will work!

Comment: I know this is very old question but i have one issue with my gridview in which i have used different `controller` action in `actioncolumn` and gridview is in `pjax` so when i click on the button it doesnt open a whole new page it just refreshes the gridview. any idea how can i solve it?

Answer (score 22):

You need to set $controller property of yii\grid\ActionColumn. In your case, try this:

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'controller' => 'itempicture'
]
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-actioncolumn.html#$controller-detail

If you are using yii\data\ArrayDataProvider, make sure you set $key property like:

$dataProvider->key = 'id'; //id is the primary key name of your Itempicture model.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider.html#$key-detail

Hope it helps.

Comment: If you use SqlDataprovider you also have to set $dataProvider->key = 'id';

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
[
   'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
   'template'    => '{view}',
   'controller' => 'ItempictureController'
]
```

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/output-data-widgets.md#action-column

Comment: simple and efficient solution :-)

Comment: that does not work, since urlCreate turns this route to 'ItempictureController/view' . but the r-string has to be 'itempicture/view'

Answer (score 3):

```
[
   'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
   'template'    => '{view}',
   'controller' => 'itempicture'
]
```

Comment: Its often better to have a brief explanation than to have code-only answers.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the controller variable to work , even though it has in the past.

Had to resort to:

```
   [
     'class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
     'urlCreator' => function($action, $model, $key, $index) { 
             return Url::to(['/new-test/'.$action,'id'=>$key]);
     },...]
```

Remember when the controller is something like NewTestController the actual link url should be 'new-test/action'